# PHP Startup: Failed opening index.php after composer install/update

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I've uploaded my webapp (made with Laravel 5.8). I run *composer install* via SSH so vendor is created, but when opening website I get:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /index.php on line 24

Fatal error: PHP Startup: Failed opening required '//../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/:/usr/local/php72/lib/pear') in /index.php on line 24
```

When I change server's PHP default version, for example to 7.1, in second line path changes to: usr/local/php71/lib/pear .

On localhost, and on different with the very same vendor everything works fine.

So I assume something is wrong with php's path?

I've already run *composer update* or dumb-autoload with no success.

E1:

```
define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `comoser install` run correctly to the end? I would expect that  your autoload file isn't generated correctly during the process.

Comment: There are no errors shown, so I assume it is being installed correctly

Comment: And when the error appears is the autoload.php ok? Can you post the `index.php` to see if your includes are ok?

Comment: I've posted index.php content, but I dont think problem is there, as the very same index works on different server / local host

Comment: What are the permissions on the vendor folder? Did you run `composer install` as root user?

Comment: Permissions for directories are 755, 644 for files

Answer (score 0):

try to run following command in your application

```
sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache storage
```